# Return an array of chars c++ to C# array

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I am using Tesseract to extract text from images(OCR). This is working just fine.

Previously I was parsing a filename from C# to my C++ DLL(DLL handles OCR part).

Now I want to optimize the process and parse in a directory and return an array of the text for each image.

I want to return an array containing the following:

[0] = File 1 text
[1] = File 2 text

This is the code I currently have:

```
 char** OCRWrapper::ReadAllPages(char* path, char* lang, char* imgPath)
    {
        std::vector<char*> charArr;
        DIR* pDirectory;
        struct dirent *entry;
        if (pDirectory = opendir(imgPath))
        {
            std::string imgPathString = imgPath;
            std::vector<int> fileNames;
            while (entry = readdir(pDirectory))
            {
                std::string fullPath = imgPathString + "\\" + entry->d_name;
                if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0)
                {
                    std::string filename = entry->d_name;
                    filename = filename.replace(filename.find("."), 1, "");
                    filename = filename.replace(filename.find("p"), 1, "");
                    filename = filename.replace(filename.find("n"), 1, "");
                    filename = filename.replace(filename.find("g"), 1, "");
                    fileNames.push_back(atoi(filename.c_str()));
                }
            }
            closedir(pDirectory);
            std::sort(fileNames.begin(), fileNames.end());
            for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.size(); i++)
            {
                std::string fullFileName = imgPathString + "\\" + std::to_string(fileNames[i]) + ".png";
                char* pFileText = GetUTF8Text(path, lang, &fullFileName[0]);
                if (pFileText == NULL)
                {
                    pFileText = "";
                }
                charArr.push_back(pFileText);
            }
        }
        //What do I do here??? I need to convert charArr to an char* array and return the text for each index.
        char** p = charArr.data();
        return p;
    }
char** p = charArr.data() //only returns the first value in the array.
```

Hope it makes sense.

I need to parse the array to C#.

Thank you.

Comment: When you post code here, you should consider removing consecutive blank lines to limit scrolling needed to see the code and you should also double check your indentation for readability.

Comment: @crashmstr: thanks I changed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you should first allocate memory for `p`, and then copy each value of `charArr` to `p`.
Or, if you are sure about the size of `charArr` I think your
`char** p = charArr.data();` should do the trick.

I don't understand what you mean with

> //only returns the first value in the array.

Did you iterate over `p`?
Sorry if I haven't understood correctly.

EDIT:: Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<char*> v;
  v.push_back("Hello");
  v.push_back("my");
  v.push_back("Friend");
  v.push_back("!");
  std::for_each (v.begin(), v.end(), [&](char* value)
  {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  });
  char** v_ptr = v.data();
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
      std::cout << v_ptr[i] << std::endl;
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char** p = charArr.data();` only returns the first element in the `charArr` array. Therefore the remaining values is not added.

Comment: I tried a simpler example with a vector of int:
`
  #include <iostream>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <vector>

  int main()
  {
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.push_back(10);
   v.push_back(23);
   v.push_back(45);
   v.push_back(64);

   std::for_each (v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int value)
   {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
   });

   int *v_ptr = v.data();
   for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   {
    std::cout << v_ptr[i] << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
  }`

Comment: @FouadSsitou check my edit in the answer. Perhaps you didn't iterate correctly over `p`. Note that, when you will iterate over ``p`` you need to know the size of the original vector ``charArr``, otherwise you could read other values not belonging to ``p``, causing some errors.

Comment: As I said, you need the size of that ``char**`` array. So, if you know the size, you can iterate over it with a simple `for` loop and do your things. Or, if you know the exact char to be modified, you can access it by `p[index]`

Comment: I am quite aware that I can loop through the char array. My issue is now how to return the char** p variable to C#.

Comment: Sorry, I really can't understand what you mean with _return the char **p variable to C#_ . Can't you just return it with the function ?

Comment: Currently I have a method that returns just a single char* and I use marshaling to read it and that is working fine, but now I need to read an IntrPtr that contains a IntrPtr...???

Comment: From what I can see, that function returns `p`, where `p` has ``char**`` type. Anyway, I don't know anything about C#, so I can't really be more helpful, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Michael, Thank you for your help.